# Giant pogo pin or spring probe pin for registration during electrical test

Tags: pins, electrical, test

Solved:  if you search for "GP-2 PCB Board Umbrella Shape 5.3mm Tip Testing Probe Pins Receptacles" you will find these probes!  Thanks for the help!

[image: GP-2 PCB Board Umbrella probe]

I am designing an electrical test fixture, and I have all the probes figured out for testing pads and soldered pins for terminals.

However, I am having a hard time finding any pogo pins that would partiall fit into a 0.155" mounting holes, to act as registration points and guide the device under test down onto all of the probing pins.

I know that at least one must exist, since I found it in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCB625Ps19E&t=39).

Here is a picture of the giant registration or locator probe for the four 
mounting holes.

[image: Here is a picture of the giant registration or locator probe for the four mounting holes.]

Can anyone suggest a proper name or part number or search term for this device?

It is not in the IDI (Smiths Connectors) or ECT Contact Products websites as far as I can tell, and the google searching results failed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please be aware that shopping questions get closed very quickly. I recommend that you edit your question to remove the shopping question and change it to something like "Can you suggest a proper name or search term for this device?"

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use spring-pins for the giant registration holes. Metal dowels/pins will work just fine to align the board. You might find it difficult to source large spring-pins.

Comment: I use non-sprung metal pins for locating.  If you really want sprung you're now at a macroscopic scale where making something is plausible.  Also check places like McMaster-Carr for mechanical items (turns out they have pogos and pogo sockets, too, though expensively)

Comment: I have large-diameter pogo pins from a company named "Pylon". No idea where to purchase them from and I am away from my shop, so can't give you the part number. But perhaps see if Google knows anything about that company.

Comment: @Dwayne so he must construct additional pylons?

Comment: If you search for "GP-2 PCB Board Umbrella Shape 5.3mm Tip Testing Probe Pins Receptacles"   you will find them.   Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: @zminer answers go in the answer box below, not as edits to the question.  Revert your edit and post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Pogo pin test fixtures should not use pogo pins for the alignments posts for the DUT (device under test). Instead the proper method is to use machined metal posts that slide into two or more mounting or guide holes of the DUT. These posts are secured to the same base plate that the pogo pin sockets are mounted. The alignment posts are tall enough that they locate the board before it engages with the testpoint pogo pins.

Sometimes you can use a technique to lower the friction of the alignment posts in the holes of the DUT by specifying three flats on the sides of the alignment posts as shown here:

[image]

*<sup>(Note that the flats would normally be uniform and less exaggerated than shown in this quick sketch).</sup>*